# OpenLayers Feature is not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-5

I'm starting to play a bit with `OpenLayers5` but I cannot even draw a simple point on the map.
I followed the tutorials and had a grasp at some of the examples but they always try to achieve more complex things that what I wanted to accomplish: Draw a single point on the map.

I'm definitely missing something but I cannot see what it is. I created the `map` and added a `VectorLayer` with a `VectorSource` containing my single point to be drawn. Yet nothing appears on the `TilesLayer`used as a base...

Hints/Directions on what I'm missing are very much welcome :). I'm sure I'm missing some small detail but I cannot overcome it.

This is my `JS` file:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map,View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize, false);



function initialize() {

  var mapCenter = [-5.93, 43.52]; // Long, lat
  var pointCoords = [-5.93, 43.52];

  var features = [
    new Feature(new Point(pointCoords))
  ];


  const map = new Map({
    target: 'mapCanvas',
    layers: [
     new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      }),
      new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          features: features
        })
      })
    ],
    view: new View({
      center: fromLonLat(mapCenter),
      zoom: 12
    })
  });

}
```

And the simple HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/posiciones.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
    <div id="sideMenu"></div>


    <script src="js/posiciones.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transform the point coordinates from (Lon, Lat) to WebMercator via `fromLatLon(pointCoords);` before creating the feature.

Comment: Hello RalphL, indeed this was the issue, I needed to convert the point coordinates first.... Thank you so much for pointing this out. Happy holidays :)